# Calculating j - a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, filters

Using a shortcut to get the magnitude for a filter, to get the magnitude at 0.25Fs you can replace z (from the transfer function) with 'j' - a complex number derived from:  $$ {e^{j(Pi/2)}}$$

(where pi is 180 degrees in this case)

so it said somewhere that getting the gain for this filter:

$$\frac{z}{z - 0.8}$$

you can replace z with j and it becomes:

$$\frac{j}{j - 0.8}$$

and here is where I'm confused, it somehow calculates to 
$$\frac{1}{1.28} = 0.78$$

how is j being calculated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are calculating the magnitude of the fraction.  $$\left|\frac j{j-0.8}\right|=\frac {|j|}{|j-0.8|}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+0.8^2}}\approx \frac 1{1.28}\approx 0.78$$

Comment: Alright I see!, interesting  but i've no idea how the  |j - 0.8| comes to be sqrt(1 + 0.8^2), were you following a complex number principle or something?  the sqrt(a^2 + b^2)  pattern looks familiar

Comment: Yes, if you have a complex number $a+bi$, with $a,b$ real, its magnitude is $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$.  The $a$ and $bi$ are orthogonal (one horizontal, one vertical), so we use Pythagoras.  You could see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument)

Comment: Right I see, thank you